# Using expand to concatenate .tab files in subdirectories which are variables themselves

Tags: python, cat, snakemake, wildcard-expansion

I have two variables and I would like to concatenate all .tab files for "BOB" and "LISA" separately. How to do this in snakemake? With `expand` like below it is concatenating all tab files for both BOB and LISA together.

```
GENES=["BOB","LISA"]
SAMPLES=["FB_399","FB_400"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("/path/to/{gene}/ALL_final.tab", gene=GENES)
   
...some other code here which produces tab file"

rule cat:
    input:
         expand("/path/to/{gene}/{sample}.annotation.tab", sample=SAMPLES, gene=GENES)
    output:
         temp("/path/to/{gene}/all.tab"),
         "/path/to/{gene}/ALL_final.tab"
    shell:
        """
        awk 'FNR > 1 {{print FILENAME "\t" $0}}' {input[0]} > {output[0]}
        sed -i 's/.annotation.tab//g' {output[0]}
        cat header.txt {output[0]} > {output[1]}
        """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep specific wildcards as variables during expansion, embrace them in double curly brackets `{{like_so}}`. For example, `expand('{a}_{{b}}', a=[1,2])` will generate `['1_{b}', '2_{b}]`.

In your specific case, the following should work:

```py
rule cat:
    input:
         expand("/path/to/{{gene}}/{sample}.annotation.tab", sample=SAMPLES)
    output:
         temp("/path/to/{gene}/all.tab"),
         "/path/to/{gene}/ALL_final.tab"
    shell:
        """
        awk 'FNR > 1 {{print FILENAME "\t" $0}}' {input[1]} > {output[0]}
        sed -i 's/.annotation.tab//g' {output[0]}
        cat header.txt {output[0]} > {output[1]}
        """
```

Comment: Thanks! that was easy... I thought I have to do some constraints..

Comment: For this case, it's this simple, but there could be more complex cases, e.g. when not all outputs are known in advance, things get trickier... (re: checkpoints).